# How to omit names of outer XML elements

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I need to produce XML files like this one:

```xml
  <package>
    <dc:contributor id="creator1">John Doe</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">A01</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="file-as">Doe, John</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
    <dc:contributor id="reviewer1">Mary Poppins</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">rev</meta>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="file-as">Poppins, Mary</meta>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
    <dc:contributor id="translator1">Alfred Weasley</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">trl</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">B06</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="file-as">Weasley, Alfred</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
  </package>
```

The ordering is important here.

I use this structuring:

```golang
type Pack struct {
    XMLName struct{}        `xml:"package"`
    People  []PersonWrapper `xml:""` // <-- is this the problem?
}

type Person struct {
    Id       string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name     string `xml:"-"`
    Surname  string `xml:"-"`
    FullName string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type Meta struct {
    Refines  string `xml:"refines,attr"`
    Property string `xml:"property,attr"`
    Scheme   string `xml:"scheme,attr,omitempty"`
    Value    string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type PersonWrapper struct {
    Person Person `xml:"dc:contributor"`
    Metas  []Meta `xml:"meta"`
}
```

With this I got:

```xml
<package>
  <People>
    <dc:contributor id="creator1">John Doe</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">A01</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="file-as">Doe, John</meta>
    <meta refines="creator1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
  </People>
  <People>
    <dc:contributor id="reviewer1">Mary Poppins</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">rev</meta>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="file-as">Poppins, Mary</meta>
    <meta refines="reviewer1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
  </People>
  <People>
    <dc:contributor id="translator1">Ben Weasley</dc:contributor>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">trl</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">B06</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="file-as">Weasley, Ben</meta>
    <meta refines="translator1" property="diplay-seq">1</meta>
  </People>
</package>
```

How to get rid of the `<People/>` outer tags? I tried to wrap the inner structure into other structs on a higher level but can't reach the desired structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [`xml.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) interface for `PersonWrapper` (and add xmlnames to the nested structs).

```golang
type Pack struct {
    XMLName struct{} `xml:"package"`
    People  []PersonWrapper
}

type Person struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"dc:contributor"`
    Id       string   `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name     string   `xml:"-"`
    Surname  string   `xml:"-"`
    FullName string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type Meta struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"meta"`
    Refines  string   `xml:"refines,attr"`
    Property string   `xml:"property,attr"`
    Scheme   string   `xml:"scheme,attr,omitempty"`
    Value    string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type PersonWrapper struct {
    Person Person `xml:"dc:contributor"`
    Metas  []Meta `xml:"meta"`
}

func (pw PersonWrapper) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if err := e.Encode(pw.Person); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := e.Encode(pw.Metas); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hzrBdHXHwOB

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Also omitting xml tags in PersonWrapper could be done in addition (seems to me). I guess it would be for another question but for a sake of completeness – with adding `xml.Name` into `Meta` and `Person` means I need to pass `xml.Name{}` whilst creating real sturcts, right?

Comment: @HonzaHejzl tldr; what matters is the field name `XMLName`, the type is not relevant in this case. The long version of it: Nope, you don't have to pass it, you can also use `struct{}` like you do with `Pack`, I used `xml.Name` out of habit. The point is that the names for the two structs *must* be specified "inside" them because in the `MarshalXML` method the values of those types are passed directly, so there's no way for the marshaler to know the names from the tags of `PersonWrapper`, i.e. from "outside"... I hope that make sense.